# Wordpress Feedwordpress plugin Fatal error: memory exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49100354 bytes) in /home/organic/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 376

I am trying to pull in 50mb feed and getting this error. I already tried increasing memory limit to 512m and 1024m, max upload size and max post size but no luck. Anybody have any clue for me?

I am on VPS and have much freedom to php upgrades.